# Prettier formats files specified in .prettierignore

Tags: prettier, prettier-eslint

When running the command `pnpm exec prettier . --write` files which supposedly should be specified to be ignored in `.prettierignore` are not being ignored.

My `.prettierignore`, located in the root folder next to `.prettier`, looks like this:

```
.*
node_modules
build
package*
```

Files such at `.github/workflows/main.yml` are being formatted and I don't get why as `.*` should match the path as far as I know.
My package.json is being formatted as well even though `package*` matches that.

I've also tried the following:

```
.*
.*/
node_modules
build
package*
**/*.yml
```

I don't know if it makes a difference but I also have ESLint in my project.